# Can i use formula field as trigger in work flow rules based on the formula field time

Tags: workflow

I am calculating time in formula field like this Now()-CreatedDate
i am getting result like this  [image]

after 30 minute formula field will become zero than i need to send email to contact  Is it possible 
please share idea 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Time-Depended](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1) workflow, or [scheduled action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US&type=0)s in process builder.

1. Specify criteria, when email should be sent
2. Add time-depended workflow action